# pyodbc InterfaceError: sqlalchemy.create_engine(mssql+pyodbc://...)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

The `create_engine()` statement doesn't seem to work when using `mssql+pyodbc`, it throws an `InterfaceError`. The same happens when I try to use `turbodbc`. However, it works fine when using `mssql+pymssql`.

Mainly, I'm trying to speed up my `df.to_sql()` operation. To that end, I tried two options.

1. using pyodbc and implementing `fastexecutemany = True`.
2. using `turbodbc`.

Both options throw the same error when used in the `create_engine()` command.

I am using Windows 10 and Windows Authentication, Python 3.7.

The connection can be established using pyodbc. So, this works:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                          "Server=server;"
                          "Database=database;"
                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

I CAN DO:

```
cnx = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://@server/database')
df.to_sql(name = name, con=cnx, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

I CANNOT DO:

```
cnx = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@server/database')
df.to_sql(name = name, con=cnx, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

I get the following error message:

```
InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

Inerestingly, the same thing happens when I try

```
cnx = create_engine('mssql+turbodbc://@server/database')
```

Clearly, something in the way I set up my engine and try to connect to the database fails.

Comment: The most common approach (preferred by SQLAlchemy) for `mssql+pyodbc` is to create an ODBC DSN and then use `mssql+pyodbc://@dsn_name`

Comment: Well, I don't have a dsn. I've been given access to the database by someone else and I wouldn't know how to create a dsn. Also, any idea why it's not working dsn-less?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections

Comment: Thanks, this was actually really helpful (specifiying the driver solved my problem for both ```pyodbc``` and ```turbodbc```. Can't belive I was unable to find that myself! Thanks and best,